# jQuery .cookie with .delay?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a cookie with a delayed amount of time.

I want the cookie to be set after 80 minutes on the page.

here is my code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // Set the cookie after 81 mins so the next visit has the button
            $.cookie('EVGSalesLetter', 'visited').delay(4860000); 
        });
```

Comment: I think delay() is supposed to come *before* the thing you want to delay. :)

Comment: 4 spaces before a line formats as code. `ctr-k` for a selection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is for the animation queue, to just generally set a timer use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { $.cookie('EVGSalesLetter', 'visited'); }, 4860000);
```

I didn't stick this in a `document.ready` because I'm assuming (hopefully safely...) that ater 81 minutes your page has fully loaded :)

Comment: This is of course 81 minutes continuously on the page as opposed to 81 cumulative minutes on the page (which could be tracked with a cookie)

Comment: @MWoodward...award Nick at least with a 'RIGHT ANSWER' check.

Comment: underscore.js has a _.delay() function that is a little nicer looking than setTimeout() if one's so inclined to try some new tools!